# jsplumb deleteEndpoint not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm having an issue with jsPlumb's deleteEndpoint function.

I want to delete endpoints that don't have any connections on them. I'd like for this to trigger on "connection", but I think there might be some issues with it there.

But I moved my code to "dblclick" and I am seeing the same problem. One of the nodes marked for deletion gets deleted but then EVERY endpoint in the system gets frozen in place - disconnected from it's element once its dragged. I'm not sure what's causing it: here's the relevant code and some screenshots...

```
jsPlumb.bind("dblclick", function(c) { 

            alert('starting...');

            var endpoints_to_delete = new Array();
            jsPlumb.selectEndpoints({source:c.sourceId}).each(function(endpoint) {
                if( endpoint.connections.length <= 0 )
                    endpoints_to_delete.push(endpoint);
            });
            jsPlumb.selectEndpoints({source:c.targetId}).each(function(endpoint) {
                if( endpoint.connections.length <= 0 )
                    endpoints_to_delete.push(endpoint);
            });

            alert(endpoints_to_delete.length); // 3

            $.each(endpoints_to_delete, function(endpoint) {
                jsPlumb.deleteEndpoint(endpoint);
            });

        });
```

Here's the graph before I attempt to delete the endpoints - all endpoints are still intact with the draggable elements they are attached to. 
[image: Graph before attempt to delete extra endpoints]

After attempting to delete an endpoint, EVERY endpoint gets disconnected from its element...
[image: Graph after dblclick attempt to delete extra endpoints]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786329/jsplumb-1-4-1-deleteendpoint-by-uuid-or-object-example?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through each element individually and deleting the endpoints worked for me - I think the references to the endpoints on the second element were getting mauled when I started working with endpoints from the first element. Hn.

```
    deleteEmptyEndpoints: function(element)
    {
        var endpoints_to_delete = [];
        jsPlumb.selectEndpoints({source:element}).each(function(endpoint) {
            console.log(endpoint);
            if( !!endpoint && endpoint.connections.length <= 0 )
            {
                console.log('marking ' + endpoint.getId() + ' for deletion');
                endpoints_to_delete.push(endpoint);
            }
        });

        $.each(endpoints_to_delete, function(index, endpoint) {
            console.log('deleting endpoint: ' + endpoint);
            jsPlumb.deleteEndpoint(endpoint);
            console.log('endpoint deleted');

        });
    }
```